# JavaFX FileDialog focus

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, filedialog

I am now trying to make focus to FX FileDialog. When i click outside the dialog, dialog is outfocused. Its any way to make when i click outside, the dialog call any metod that make him visible (focused)? TY :)

I just tried any like this.

```
...focusedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> System.out.println(newVal ? "Focused" : "Unfocused"));
```

and maeby this way...

```
fileChooser.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN, new EventHandler<WindowEvent>(){
                        @Override
                        public void handle(WindowEvent window)
                        {...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle focus  using `addEventHandler` inside `javafx.stage.FileChooser`,
 But you can simply use `primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` to make your  `FileChooser` always visible on top of other windows

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXtest5 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Test");

        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                chooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
                primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello Dialog!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```